# Beginner having problem with starting Ubuntu

Tags: server, mysql

I have contracted with OVH a dedicated VPS. All good, but today I had to restart for a problem and it didn't start. I have tried everything, I have called OVH and I have been told that it is not their problem (something normal) and I do not know how to fix it. It gives me the following errors:

```
[FAILED] Failed to Start MYSQL Community Server
[FAILED] Failed to Start OpenBSD Secure Shell Server
[TIME] Timed Out waiting for device dev-vdb.device
[TIme] Timed out waiting for device dev-ttyS0.device
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Seruall Getty on ttySO
```

I have tried everything but my Linux level is beginner and I do not know how to fix it.
Thank you very much!

Comment: `journalctl -b -xn` is the command to show the logs. Anything in there?

Comment: Being a server in rescue mode that gives me OVH tells me: "no journal file were found" and I can not see the logs.

Comment: Anything before "[FAILED] Failed to Start MYSQL Community Server"
 (I would expect an error notice. These are just conclusions). Oh and /var/log/ has to have notifications from errors with mysql.

Comment: I think Ubuntu can not find an additional disk "/data" and I have a symbolic link in Wordpress/wp-content /uploads.  It may be that when initiating is giving problems?

Comment: Did you add this disk to /etc/fstab ?

Comment: Yes , I do. If everything went well until Uubntu rebooted and when I initied salt the errors I put in the post and: [DEPEND] Dependency failed for /data [DEPEND] Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/vdb @Rinzwind

Comment: I have already solved the errors of / data but the errors of ttySO I am blocked, Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

For the ttySO error I have been searching for forums and I have used these commands
`systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service`
It has answered me

`Active failed`

And I have executed the following command
`/lib/systemd/system-modules-load
Failed to insert ipmi_si No such device`

For the ttySO error I have been looking for forums and I have used these commands
'Systemctl state systemd-modules-load.service'
He has answered me

'Active Error'

And I have executed the following command
`/Lib /systemd /system-modules-load
Error inserting ipmi_si No device of this type`

Can that be why it does not start?